# Using Equals with LINQ on an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

this code :

```
var allSubjectsForAStudent =    GetAllSubjects<Subject>(studentId);
```

returns an

```
IEnumerable<Subject>
```

and I can see bunch of subjects returned in the debugger.

Want to check for a particular Subject doing a case insensitive comparison.

This is the code that I have:

```
var studentSubjects = allSubjectsForAStudent.Where(s => s.Name.Equals(subjectName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

'subjectName' is a parameter that the method will recieve.

When this line executes I get the 'Object not set to an instance of an object' error.

So what I want to do is a CASE INSENSITIVE search and return the first item when there are more than one and return an empty collection when there are none.

Any clues?

**Edit 1**

The answers suggest that there can be an entry in the first collection which might have a 'null'. While the observation is true the program makes sure that the 'Subject Name' can not be a null value. Hope this helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an item in the collection that's name is `null`? That's the most likely cause.

Comment: I'm tempted to close as duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)... but I'm compelled to tell you that you haven't shown us enough code to even diagnose a problem.  The problem is in how you got your subjects.  Something there is `null` but there's no way of us knowing because you haven't shown us any of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
var studentSubjects = allSubjectsForAStudent.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Name) && s.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == subjectName.ToUpperInvariant()).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will either set `studentSubjects` to null or the first instance in the `IEnumerable` that matches.

You're getting a NullReferenceException when you call

```
s.Name.Equals(subjectName)
```

for an object where s.Name is null.

Comment: Rosenheimer, this gives 'Sequence Contains No Elements' when there is no match.

Comment: I fixed it, I should have used FirstOrDefault instead of only First. Should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

It will :

```
if(allSubjectsForAStudent!=null && !string.IsNullorEmpty(subjectName))
var studentSubjects = allSubjectsForAStudent.Where(s => s.Name.Equals(subjectName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
```